# Calculating the the number of different levels of severity from acquiring a certain number of infections

Tags: probability, statistics

A certain infectious disease of humans is caused by a virus. There are seven main viral strains, and an individual can never be infected by the same strain twice. However, a second infection can occur by any of the other strains. The severity of the second infection depends on the identity of both the strain that caused the first infection and the strain causing the second infection, as well as the order in which these were acquired. How many different levels of severity are possible for an individual acquiring a second infection?

I tried $$7!6!$$ since order matters and the person can't be infected by the same strain twice.

However, I can't figure out how to find an expression to account for the severity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 7(6) = 42 possible orders in which two different strains
can infect any one person. (Your method seems to take into account
infection by more than two strains, and in a way I cannot
see as relevant to your question.)

If letters A through G represent the 7 strains, then 42 possible
combinations would be as follows (where -- is an impossible repeat
infection with the same strain). Notice that order is counted as
important here because, for example, AB and BA are both listed.

`-- AB AC AD AE AF AG
BA -- BC BD BE BF BG
CA CB -- CD CE CF CG
DA DB DC -- DE DF DG
EA EB EC ED -- EF EG
FA FB FC FD FE -- FG
GA GB GC GD GE GF --`

Potentially, then there might be as many as 42 different
levels of severity of the second infection. Without knowing specifics it would be
impossible to say whether all of these 42 levels would be
different for practical purposes.

Perhaps you have data that would allow you to classify
severity of second infection by each of the 42 possibilities as
"Mild", "Intermediate", or "Severe".  But that would be based
on data and expert interpretation, rather than by counting exercise.